# Using bicep to create a storage account that requires a private endpoint and a customer managed key

Tags: powershell, azure-bicep

I am trying to use bicep to create an Azure storage account that uses a customer managed key. I have got something at the moment, but it is very messy, you have to run 3 x deployments and then a manual change to the storage account to link it with the key created  within key vault. The last step involves running a PowerShell script that will rotate the key.

**What am i trying to achieve ?**

A simple modularised script that uses modules to achieve the above. The network configuration already exists and so does the key vault.

From what I have read up. It needs to be in the order below.

1. Create a key within an existing key vault.
2. Create a storage account
   that uses a private endpoint and link it to the key created in step
   1
3. Rotate the key using PowerShell if it exists.

I have got a template below which will almost achieve the above but without the private endpoint.

```
param keyName string = ''
param keyVersion string = ''
param vaultName string = ''
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param accountName string = 'tetsdfgfgdffd'

resource storageAcc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
  name: accountName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
  dependsOn: []
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2016-10-01' = {
  name: vaultName
  location: 'eastasia'
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: []
    enabledForDeployment: true
    enabledForDiskEncryption: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enableSoftDelete: true
  }
}

module updateStorageAccount './enableEncryption.bicep' = {
  name: 'updateStorageAccount'
  params: {
    msiObjectId: storageAcc.identity.principalId
    vaultUri: keyVault.properties.vaultUri
    vaultName: vaultName
    accountName: accountName
    location: location
    keyName: keyName
    keyversion: keyVersion
  }
}
```

**What have I got working so far ?**

This creates the storage account.

```
var privateStorageBlobDnsZoneName = 'privatelink.blob.${environment().suffixes.storage}'
var privateEndpointStorageBlobName = 'pep-${blobStorageAccountName}-blob-001'
var subnet = resourceId(vnetRG, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, subnetName)
var commonTags = {
  Application: applicationTag
  Criticality: criticalityTag
  Department: departmentTag
  Environment: environmentTag
  Owner: ownerTag
}
var appliedTags = union(commonTags, tags)


// Private Endpoints
resource privateEndpointStorageBlobName_blobPrivateDnsZoneGroup 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: privateEndpointStorageBlob
  name: 'blobPrivateDnsZoneGroup'
  properties: {
    privateDnsZoneConfigs: [
      {
        name: 'config'
        properties: {
          privateDnsZoneId: extensionResourceId('/subscriptions/${dnsZoneSubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${dnsZoneRG}', 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones', privateStorageBlobDnsZoneName)
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource privateEndpointStorageBlob 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2021-05-01' = {
  name: privateEndpointStorageBlobName
  location: location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: subnet
    }
    customNetworkInterfaceName: '${privateEndpointStorageBlobName}-nic'
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: 'MyStorageBlobPrivateLinkConnection'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: blobStorageAccount.id
          groupIds: [
            'blob'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  tags: appliedTags
}

resource blobStorageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: blobStorageAccountName
  location: location
  tags: appliedTags
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: skuName
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    accessTier: accessTier
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    isHnsEnabled: isHnsEnabled
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
  }
}


// Storage Account SystemAssigned Managed Identity
@description('The Principal ID of the System Assigned Managed Identity for the new Storage Account.')
output storageAccount_ManagedIdentity string = blobStorageAccount.identity.principalId
```

**Attach the private end point to the created storage account.**

```
var privateStorageBlobDnsZoneName = 'privatelink.blob.${environment().suffixes.storage}'
var privateEndpointStorageBlobName = 'pep-${blobStorageAccountName}-blob-001'
var subnet = resourceId(vnetRG, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, subnetName)
var commonTags = {
  Application: applicationTag
  Criticality: criticalityTag
  Department: departmentTag
  Environment: environmentTag
  Owner: ownerTag
}
var appliedTags = union(commonTags, tags)


// Private Endpoints
resource privateEndpointStorageBlobName_blobPrivateDnsZoneGroup 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: privateEndpointStorageBlob
  name: 'blobPrivateDnsZoneGroup'
  properties: {
    privateDnsZoneConfigs: [
      {
        name: 'config'
        properties: {
          privateDnsZoneId: extensionResourceId('/subscriptions/${dnsZoneSubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${dnsZoneRG}', 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones', privateStorageBlobDnsZoneName)
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource privateEndpointStorageBlob 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2021-05-01' = {
  name: privateEndpointStorageBlobName
  location: location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: subnet
    }
    customNetworkInterfaceName: '${privateEndpointStorageBlobName}-nic'
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: 'MyStorageBlobPrivateLinkConnection'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: blobStorageAccount.id
          groupIds: [
            'blob'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  tags: appliedTags
}

resource blobStorageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: blobStorageAccountName
  location: location
  tags: appliedTags
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: skuName
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    accessTier: accessTier
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    isHnsEnabled: isHnsEnabled
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
  }
}


// Storage Account SystemAssigned Managed Identity
@description('The Principal ID of the System Assigned Managed Identity for the new Storage Account.')
output storageAccount_ManagedIdentity string = blobStorageAccount.identity.principalId
```

**This creates the key within an existing vault.**

```
param keyVaultname string
param keyName string
param keyOps array = [
  'sign'
  'verify'
  'encrypt'
  'decrypt'
  'wrapKey'
  'unwrapKey'
]
param keyType string = 'RSA'
param keySize int = 3072
param versionExpiryDays int = 180
param rotateBeforeExpiry int = 30

// Resource Lookups
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultname
}


resource kvKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-02-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: keyName
  properties: {
    keyOps: keyOps
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
    }
    keySize: keySize
    kty: keyType

    rotationPolicy:{
      attributes: { 
        expiryTime: 'P${versionExpiryDays}D'
      }
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          action: {
            type: 'rotate'
          }
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P${rotateBeforeExpiry}D'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


// Outputs
output keyVersionUri string = kvKey.properties.keyUriWithVersion
output keyUri string = kvKey.properties.keyUri
output keyName string = kvKey.name
```

Then I have to manually link the key to the storage account configuration. The entire process is long winded and sub optimal. The last step is a PS script that I have to run to rotate the key.

**Now rotate the key using Ps, ideally from the output of the bicep code such that its not a manual step**

```
# Connect-AzAccount

$keyVaultsName = @('my-kv')
foreach ($KeyVaultName in $KeyVaultsName)
{
    $keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $KeyVaultName
    foreach ($key in $keys) {
        # Rotate the key
        $newKeyVersion = Invoke-AzKeyVaultKeyRotation -VaultName $KeyVaultName -KeyName $key.Name

        Write-Host "Key rotation completed for $($key.Name). New version: $($newKeyVersion.Version)"
    }

    Write-Host "Key rotation completed for all keys in $KeyVaultName."
}
```

Comment: using a user assigned identity would help here as you could assign permission to kv before creating the storage account

Comment: also you can configure automatic rotation policy on the key vault key, then if you omit the key version while configuring cmk on the storage, that would achieve automatic rotation

Comment: also is it related to cmk or private endpoint ? it feels there are multiple questions here

Comment: it relates to both, a customer managed key and a private endpoint for the storage account to use. The network and key vault already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- Update your api-version to target newer api: this will give your more options
- Use a user-assigned identity: you will be able to assign permission before creating the storage account
- Achieve automatic rotation by auto-rotate in kv and not specifying the key version while deploying the storage account

Here is a complete bicep sample.

key-vault-role-assignment.bicep

```
param keyVaultName string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'
param roleId string

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, keyVaultName, roleId, principalId)
  scope: keyVault
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}
```

main .bicep:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param keyVaultName string = 'thomastestkv725'
param storageAccountName string = 'thomasteststr725'

param storageAccountCmkKeyName string = '${storageAccountName}-encryption-key'
param identityName string = '${storageAccountName}-identity'

// create a user assigned identity for the storage account
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: identityName
  location: location
}

// create a key vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    enableRbacAuthorization: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enablePurgeProtection: true // required when enabling CMK
    enableSoftDelete: true // required when enabling CMK
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 90
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' // require when enabling CMK
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'AzureServices' // require when enabling CMK if firewall enable
    }
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  }
}

// create the stroage account key
resource storageAccountCmkKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: storageAccountCmkKeyName
  properties: {
    kty: 'RSA' // CMK only supports RSA keys
    keySize: 4096
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
      exportable: false
    }
    rotationPolicy: {
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          trigger: {
            timeAfterCreate: 'P5M' // 5 months
          }
          action: {
            type: 'rotate'
          }
        }
        {
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P1M' // 1 months
          }
          action: {
            type: 'notify'
          }
        }
      ]
      attributes: {
        expiryTime: 'P6M' // 6 months
      }
    }
  }
}

// grant kv crypo permission to the identity
module keyVaultRoleAssignment 'key-vault-role-assignment.bicep' = {
  name: '${identityName}-${keyVaultName}-rbac'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: keyVault.name
    principalId: identity.properties.principalId
    roleId: '12338af0-0e69-4776-bea7-57ae8d297424' // Key Vault Crypto User
  }
}

// Create the storage account once the role assignment is done
resource storageAcc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      identity: {
        userAssignedIdentity: identity.id // use the user assigned identity
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Keyvault'
      keyvaultproperties: {
        keyvaulturi: keyVault.properties.vaultUri
        keyname: storageAccountCmkKey.name
        keyversion: null // do not specify version for automatic rotation
      }
      services: {
        blob: {
          enabled: true
          keyType: 'Account'
        }
        file: {
          enabled: true
          keyType: 'Account'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [ keyVaultRoleAssignment ]
}
```